# How do I tell which GPG key an RPM package was signed with?

Tags: rpm, packaging, cryptography, gpg

The cryptographic signature of an RPM can be verified with the `rpm -K` command. This returns a string containing `gpg` (or `pgp`) and ending in `OK` if the signature is in RPM's database and is valid.

If the package is not signed but the checksums are valid, you'll still get `OK`, but no `gpg`.

If the package is signed but the key is missing from the RPM database, you get `(GPG)` (capital letters) and `NOT OKAY`, followed by `(MISSING KEYS: GPG#deadbeef)`.

That's handy if I want to figure out what key I should find to install to make my package installation work.

But what if I want to verify *which* of several keys in my RPM keyring was used to sign a given package?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
rpm -qa --qf '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE} %{SIGPGP:pgpsig} %{SIGGPG:pgpsig}\n'
```

Comment: Only works if you have already installed the package, Brightlancer's solution below allows you to check a signature before installing

Comment: This works just fine even for an uninstalled package if you replace `-a` with `-p packagename.rpm`.

Answer (score 40):

There is a Signature field listed via `rpm -qpi package.rpm`, e.g.,:

```
[vagrant@vm-one ~]$ rpm -qpi puppet-3.7.4-1.el6.noarch.rpm
Name        : puppet
Version     : 3.7.4
Release     : 1.el6
Architecture: noarch
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : System Environment/Base
Size        : 6532300
License     : ASL 2.0
Signature   : RSA/SHA512, Tue 27 Jan 2015 11:17:18 PM UTC, Key ID 1054b7a24bd6ec30
Source RPM  : puppet-3.7.4-1.el6.src.rpm
Build Date  : Mon 26 Jan 2015 11:48:15 PM UTC
Build Host  : tahoe.delivery.puppetlabs.net
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Vendor      : Puppet Labs
URL         : http://puppetlabs.com
Summary     : A network tool for managing many disparate systems
Description :
Puppet lets you centrally manage every important aspect of your system using a
cross-platform specification language that manages all the separate elements
normally aggregated in different files, like users, cron jobs, and hosts,
along with obviously discrete elements like packages, services, and files.
```

Answer (score 9):

To find out which GPG key in your RPM DB signed a specfic rpm, do this:

List all the GPG keys in your RPM DB:

```
$ rpm -qa gpg-pubkey*
...
...
gpg-pubkey-b1275ea3-546d1808
...
...
```

First ensure the rpm in question *is* signed with a key in your RPM DB:

```
$ rpm -K hp/mlnx-en-utils-2.2-1.0.7.0.g0055740.rhel6u4.x86_64.rpm
hp/mlnx-en-utils-2.2-1.0.7.0.g0055740.rhel6u4.x86_64.rpm: rsa sha1 (md5) pgp md5 OK
```

You're looking for the OK at the end, and not 'NOT OK (MISSING KEYS', which will mean it has been signed, but by a key not in your RPM DB.

Right, so the rpm we're checking has been signed by a key in our RPM DB.

And then get the Key ID the rpm was signed with:

```
$ rpm -q --qf '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE} %{SIGPGP:pgpsig} %{SIGGPG:pgpsig}\n' -p hp/mlnx-en-utils-2.2-1.0.7.0.g0055740.rhel6u4.x86_64.rpm
mlnx-en-utils-2.2-1.0.7.0.g0055740.rhel6u4 RSA/SHA1, Tue Apr 14 12:34:51 2015, Key ID fadd8d64b1275ea3 (none)
```

Now you can see whether the *last 8 characters* of the Key ID (i.e. b1275ea3  from fadd8d64b1275ea3) corresponds to any of the 8 characters following gpg-pubkey- from the first command. And in this case, it does!

And then you have the key in question, so do:

```
$ rpm -qi gpg-pubkey-b1275ea3-546d1808
```

to see, in this example, that it was HP's key that signed this rpm.

Hope this helps. Took me a while to figure out. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Issue `less <rpm file>` and check the `Signature` entry, e.g.,:

```
[vagrant@vm-one ~]$ less artifactory-3.5.3.rpm
Name        : artifactory
Version     : 3.5.3
Release     : 30172
Architecture: noarch
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Development/Tools
Size        : 42286184
License     : LGPL
Signature   : (none)
Source RPM  : artifactory-3.5.3-30172.src.rpm
Build Date  : Thu 19 Mar 2015 04:47:04 PM UTC
Build Host  : artbuild2.jfrog.local
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Vendor      : JFrog Ltd.
URL         : http://www.jfrog.org
Summary     : Binary Repository Manager
Description :
The best binary repository manager around.
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root    root                     7891 Mar 19 16:47 /etc/init.d/artifactory
drwxr-xr-x    2 artifactartifact                    0 Mar 19 16:47 /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory
-rwxrwx---    1 artifactartifact                 9855 Mar 19 16:47 /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/artifactory.config.xml
-rwxrwx---    1 artifactartifact                11172 Mar 19 16:47 /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/artifactory.system.properties
-rwxrwx---    1 artifactartifact                  457 Mar 19 16:47 /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default
-rwxrwx---    1 artifactartifact                 6858 Mar 19 16:47 /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/logback.xml
-rwxrwx---    1 artifactartifact                 5470 Mar 19 16:47 /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/mimetypes.xml
drwxrwxr-x    2 root    root                        0 Mar 19 16:47 /opt/jfrog
drwxrwxr-x    2 root    root                        0 Mar 19 16:47 /opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root    root                   103424 Mar 19 16:47 /opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/artifactory-service.exe
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root    root                     1366 Mar 19 16:47 /opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/artifactory.bat
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root    root                      457 Mar 19 16:47 /opt/jfrog/artifactory/bin/artifactory.default
artifactory-3.5.3.rpm
```